# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nodeName')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I updated to the latest version of NEXTUI, now when I click a NEXTUI `Button` that is wrapped with `Link` from Next.js I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nodeName')`. It wasn't like that before. What can I do to without reversing the update since I made a lot of work with the new components.

```
    <Link href="/...">
      <Button size="lg" rounded className="bg-[#5379FE]">
        <Text color="white" className="text-md font-bold">
          Link text
        </Text>
      </Button>
    </Link>
```

[image]

Comment: I think it would help if you share a sample of the code that you suspect is causing the error.

Comment: I updated the post with code. It has to do with `Link` and `Button`. `Link` works everywhere else without a `Button` and I can click a `Button` on it's own and use it fx. to set a state. Also `Link` wrapped with `Button` works but I can only click text inside `Button` for `Link`.

Comment: Found a similar issue on nextui repo: https://github.com/nextui-org/nextui/issues/490

Comment: try wrapping your Button with <a></a>. Button is a custom component and probably can't forward ref.

Comment: @linusw No error but when I click it doesn't redirect.

Answer (score 1):

modified answer from Nextjs documentation
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link

```
import Link from 'next/link'

// `onClick`, `href`, and `ref` need to be passed to the DOM element
// for proper handling
const MyButton = React.forwardRef(({ onClick, href }, ref) => {
  return (
    <a href={href} onClick={onClick} ref={ref}>
       <Button size="lg" rounded className="bg-[#5379FE]">
        <Text color="white" className="text-md font-bold">
          Link text
        </Text>
      </Button>
    </a>
  )
})

function NextLinkWithButton() {
  return (
    <Link href="/about" passHref>
      <MyButton />
    </Link>
  )
}
```

Comment: it is just for example for you to see the place. Define the component and use as wrapper. You can use {children} instead of <Button> then put whatever needed inside.

Comment: Is there a purpose in having the `href` and the other attributes in `<a>` ? The example from Nextjs documentation seems fine without them

Comment: @JeffreyRam I am not sure if next/link absolutely needs them. My guess, passhref prop and <a> as direct children should be enough for your example, others for reusability.